# When adding a new org, do you need to apply the anchors?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I have been following http://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.1/channel_update_tutorial.html to add a new org to my network, however I noticed something about the anchors that I need clarification.

In the new configtx.yaml file for the new org, there is a part for anchor peers and it is configured for peer0 to be an anchor.

```
Organizations:
- &Org3
    # DefaultOrg defines the organization which is used in the sampleconfig
    # of the fabric.git development environment
    Name: Org3MSP

    # ID to load the MSP definition as
    ID: Org3MSP

    MSPDir: crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org3.example.com/msp

    AnchorPeers:
        # AnchorPeers defines the location of peers which can be used
        # for cross org gossip communication.  Note, this value is only
        # encoded in the genesis block in the Application section context
        - Host: peer0.org3.example.com
          Port: 7051
```

But the guide never runs the command to create the anchor.tx file.

e.g.

```
configtxgen -profile TwoOrgsChannel -outputAnchorPeersUpdate ./channel-artifacts/Org3MSPanchors.tx -channelID $CHANNEL_NAME -asOrg Org3MSP
```

And never runs the CLI container command to add this new anchor

e.g.

```
peer channel update -o orderer.example.com:7050 -c $CHANNEL_NAME -f ./channel-artifacts/Org3MSPanchors.tx
```

I continued following the steps and after successfully joining the new org to the channel, I saw in the gossip logs in the peers of the other orgs what appears to be them discovering the new org.

My questions is, does this mean that the anchor peer for the new org configured in the new configtx.yaml file automatically gets added when the new org joined or am I miss reading the logs and I still need to add the anchor for the new org to the channel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, let me clarify. The fact peers are capable to discover new organization, is due to fact that peers of new organization used anchor peers of already available organizations in the channel. Thus in your experiment it appeared that new peers was discovered.

The process work as following, once peer joins the channel it learns available anchor peers and introduces itself to all anchors peers enabling other peers of the organizations to expand membership. To keep this process symmetry it's good practice to have all organization publishing theirs anchors. Therefore despite the fact those steps are missing from documentation I'd advise to follow them and update anchors for new organization as well.

Comment: Right, so the discovery occurred because anchors existed already, but peer0.org3 at this point is not an anchor itself. That clears it up, and thanks for explaining the anchor peer process also as that didn't quite make sense to me either.